# rvest Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404

Tags: r, rvest

I was trying to scrape a website to extract the data from many pages using rvest and purrr. but everytime I run the code the "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404." appears.

```
url <- "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-%d"

map_df(1:10, function(i){ 
  
  page <- read_html(sprintf(url, i))
   cat(".")
  
  booksdf <- data.frame(safely( title <- html_nodes(page, "h3, #title") %>% html_text(),
                       price <- html_nodes(page, ".price_color") %>% html_text() %>% gsub("£", "", .),
                       rating <- html_nodes(page, ".star-rating") %>% html_attrs() %>% str_remove("star-rating") %>%str_replace_all(c("One" = "1", "Two" = "2", "Three" = "3", "Four" = "4", "Five" = "5")) %>%  as.numeric()
                       )
                      
  )
  
  
} 
)
```

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
```

Comment: And how is this an R coding error?

Comment: A 404 error indicates that the page you requested was not found in the server. I suggest you check to make sure you are building the correct URL. If I go to `http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2` in my browser I get a 404 error just like R. Did you forget to add the ".html" part to the URL

Comment: Thak you @MrFlick that worked. but when i run the code there's another error "Error in type(pattern) : argument "pattern" is missing, with no default"  I couldn't find any missing argument (each code runs perfect outside map_df).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create the URL's to scrape and then use `map_df` to bind the dataframes together.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-"
pages <- paste0(url, 1:10, ".html")

map_df(pages, function(i){ 
     page <- read_html(i)
     data.frame(title = html_nodes(page, "h3, #title") %>% html_text(),
                price = html_nodes(page, ".price_color") %>% html_text() %>% 
                        gsub("£", "", .),
                rating = html_nodes(page, ".star-rating") %>% html_attrs() %>% 
                         str_remove("star-rating") %>%
                         str_replace_all(c("One" = "1", "Two" = "2", 
                         "Three" = "3", "Four" = "4", "Five" = "5")) %>%  
                          as.numeric())
})


#                                            title price rating
#1                               A Light in the ... 51.77      3
#2                               Tipping the Velvet 53.74      1
#3                                       Soumission 50.10      1
#4                                    Sharp Objects 47.82      4
#5                     Sapiens: A Brief History ... 54.23      5
#6                                  The Requiem Red 22.65      1
#7                     The Dirty Little Secrets ... 33.34      4
#8                          The Coming Woman: A ... 17.93      3
#.....
```